# how to redirect to other page on selecting a particular value in dropdown in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

i want to categorise my books and create a dropdown and then i want to show only the books for the selected category.

i have created a dropdown using the following code:

```
<% form_for :category, :url => { :action => :cat_disp } do |f| %>
<%= f.select(:category, Categories.all.map {|p| [p.name,p.id]}, :prompt => "Select a category") %>
<%end%>
```

how can i show the books only for category selected from dropdown?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand what you want. It would probably be easiest to use jQuery's `change()` method to submit the form to a page that only displays books of one category.

```
$(function(){
 $(dropdown_id).change(function(){
  $(this).parent('form').get(0).submit();
 });
});
```